# An integral with square root and fractional powers

Tags: calculus, integration

How to evaluate
$$\int \sqrt{1+(1+(1+x)^{\frac{1}{4}})^\frac{1}{3}}\,\mathrm dx ?
$$
I am trying this question by substituting $1+x=u$. Then $\mathrm dx=\mathrm du$ and the integral will become
$$
\int \sqrt{1+(1+u^{\frac{1}{4}})^{\frac{1}{3}}}\,\mathrm du.
$$
Then, I am thinking of substituting $u=(\tan\theta)^8$. Now $\mathrm du = 8\,(\tan\theta)^7 \,(\sec\theta)^2 \,\mathrm d\theta$. So, finally the integral will be
$$
8 \int \sqrt{1+(\sec\theta)^{\frac{2}{3}}} \,(\tan\theta)^7\,(\sec\theta)^{2} \,\mathrm d\theta.
$$
Now I am facing problem to integrate further. So, please help me out to integrate.

Comment: @SyamprasadChakrabarti,are You aware That you can accept the answer By click on Tick option,As per your profile,None of the questions have an accepted answer

Answer (score 10):

Denote $$y \equiv \sqrt{1+\sqrt[3]{1+\sqrt[4]{1+x}}} \implies x =\left((y^2-1)^3-1\right)^4-1$$

and consider for the moment $u = 1+x$ so that $u\geq 0$ for all $y\geq \sqrt{2}$. Then, graphically, we have that

$$\int y\:du = uy - \int u\:dy$$

$$  = uy-\frac{y^{25}}{25} + \frac{12y^{23}}{23} - \frac{22y^{21}}{7} + \frac{224 y^{19}}{19} - \frac{531y^{17}}{17} + \frac{312y^{15}}{5} - \frac{1266y^{13}}{13} + \frac{1332y^{11}}{11} - 121y^9 + \frac{680y^7}{7} - \frac{312y^5}{5} + 32y^3 - 16 y + C \equiv uy - f(y) + C$$

Thus the final answer is

$$I = (1+x)\sqrt{1+\sqrt[3]{1+\sqrt[4]{1+x}}} - f\left(\sqrt{1+\sqrt[3]{1+\sqrt[4]{1+x}}}\right) + C$$

Answer (score 6):

Substituting
$y := \sqrt{1+(1+(1+x)^{\frac{1}{4}})^\frac{1}{3}}$, so that $x = [(y^2 - 1)^3 - 1]^4 - 1$, transforms the integrand to a degree-$24$ polynomial:
$$24 \int (y + 1)^2 y^2 (y - 1)^2 (y^2 - 2)^3(y^4 - y^2 + 1)^3 \,dy .$$
From this point evaluation is tedious but routine.

Comment: You are correct @Travis Willse

Comment: And also you are correct @Ninad Munshi.

Comment: But if I give the lower limit to be 2 and upper limit to be $\frac{19}{4}$, then how to find the area between the above limits?

Comment: If the question is $$\int_{2}^{\frac{19}{4}} \sqrt{1+(1+(1+x)^{\frac{1}{4}})^{\frac{1}{3}}}dx$$? Then how to solve it?

Comment: Convert the limits from $x$-values to $y$-values via the substitution formula, though the values aren't particularly nice.